# Entity Framework, assign an existing db-entity to another, without create a new one

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Each time that I want to assign a db-entity to another, I'm creating a new one.

Working with Entity Framework, code first, creating a restfull webapi service disconnected from Angular UI. For each db entity, I also have a Data obj to send result-data to UI.

Lets consider next example

DB ENTITIES:

```
Client()
{
  int Id {get;set;}
  string Name {get;set;}
  CountriesDropDown Contry { get; set; }
}

CountriesDropDown()
{
  int Id {get;set;}
  string Description {get;set;}
}
```

CountriesDropDown is a fixed list at DB, I dont want to create new rows or edit them, I just want to assign them to a Client.

**IS THERE ANY WAY TO SET THIS DROPDOWN TABLE AT ENTITY FRAMEWORK AS ALWAYS EntityState.Unchanged??**

THEN:

```
SAVE()
{
.....
.....
if(Client.Contry != null)
  {
    Client.Contry.Id = ClientData.Contry.Id;
  }
else
  { //INSTEAD OF ASSIGN AN EXISTING COUNTRY IT CREATES A DUPLICATE ONE
    Client.Contry = new CountriesDropDown();
    Client.Contry.Id = ClientData.Contry.Id;
    Client.Contry.Description = ClientData.Contry.Description;
  }
}
```

Comment: 'm not sure I got the point, but why don't you assign the country just like: Client.Contry = context.Countries.First(c => c.Id == ClientData.Contry.Id)? Entity Frameworl would manage the rest –

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways round this.

First in your `Client` class have a `CountryId` field and link it to your `Country` object via a [`ForeignKeyAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)
Then just set the Id attribute

```
Client.CountryId = clientData.CountryId
```

In querying the data you can still access the navigation property

Secondly Retrieve the existing entity via the db context and attach it

```
Client.Country = dbContext.Countries.Find(clientData.CountryId)
```